# using string in a cell as the criteria in an if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project that I am trying to keep as dynamic as I can for long-term use.  I have most of the variable data in reference tables that can be easily updated as needed.  The only issue I am having is that there are a couple if-then statements that could change in the future, and rather than expect future users to be able to work in VBA (if I am no longer here for some reason), I have a Statement cell where you just need to type in the criteria and my VBA code will input it into my if-then statement.

the statement cell is (i,20) and the variable is cs1 as string.  I can see my text in the variable via Locals Window, so I know it is reading it.  I think the issue are the "" around the text.

Is there a way to have this cell's data inputted into my if then statement?  Here is a section of my code.  Thanks

```
Dim cs1 As String
Dim cs2 As String

cn = chkdata.Cells(cm, 2) 'check number
cnm = chkdata.Cells(cm, 1) & " Check " & chkdata.Cells(cm, 2) 'check name
csrc = chkdata.Cells(cm, 7) ' Special rule yes/no
csr = Range(chkdata.Cells(cm, 8), chkdata.Cells(cm, 18)) 'check stations range
cs1 = chkdata.Cells(cm, 19) ' specific qualification statement
cs2 = chkdata.Cells(cm, 20) ' specific qualification statement2

If csrc = "No" Then
    If .Cells(i, 20) = "" Then
        .Cells(i, 20) = cnm
    Else
        .Cells(i, 20) = .Cells(i, 20) & "-" & cnm
    End If
    GoTo NextLoop
End If

If csrc = "Yes" Then
RONQual = .Cells(i, 17)
RODQual = .Cells(i, 18)
MXIS = TimeSerial(Hour(.Cells(i, 14)), Minute(.Cells(i, 14)), Second(.Cells(i, 14)))
MXOS = TimeSerial(Hour(.Cells(i, 15)), Minute(.Cells(i, 15)), Second(.Cells(i, 15)))

    If cs1 Then
        If sc2 = "" Then
            If .Cells(i, 20) = "" Then
                .Cells(i, 20) = cnm
            Else
                .Cells(i, 20) = .Cells(i, 20) & "-" & cnm
            End If
            GoTo NextLoop
```

Comment: Isn't sc2  supposed to be cs2?

Comment: What is the user expected to type in `chkdata.Cells(cm, 19)`? You're treating `cs1` like a `Boolean`.

Comment: Prior to providing an answer I'd like to confirm. You're expecting the user to type a logic statement into cell(i,20) and want to use that in your if statement in the VBA? If yes then what format will they provide the criteria in?

Comment: yes, sc2 is supposed to be cs2, but that is not the issue. (its not even getting there).  My intention is to have the user type in something like 'RONQual < 21:00'.  That would become cs1.  the if statement  'If cs1 Then' should then be 'If RONQual < 21:00 Then'

Comment: `if cs1 = "RONQual < 21:00" Then` ...doing `if cs1 Then` will just check if `cs1` is `TRUE`. Not necessarily that it is certain text.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I figured a way to incorporate a reference table to get rid of this issue.

Comment: What does the function "cs1 = chkdata.Cells(cm, 19)" do ???  Does it check if there is data in that cell, and if so loads it with the string inside the cell?  Can you show us that function?

Comment: How exactly is the user supposed to know what `RONQual` ***is*** if they aren't "able to work in VBA"?

Comment: `If Evaluate(cs1) Then` seems to work for me.